# Download an image and save it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

what's the best way to download an image and save it?

My current code is:

```
temp_file = Tempfile.new "filename", "#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/"
temp_file.puts open(path_to_picture, 'User-Agent' => 'Test').read 
mimetype = `file -ib #{temp_file.path}`.gsub(/\n/,"")
```

But it seems, that the mimetyp isn't ok.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now used the gem "rio" and it works very well!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Rails' [`send_file`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html#M000421) method. You also might want to read [File Downloads Done Right](http://therailsway.com/2009/2/22/file-downloads-done-right) over at The Rails Way.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use puts, because that writes a newline at the end of the picture.